# How to git delete a branch and a tag with the same name, both with slashes in the name?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-tag

I have a git branch and a git tag, both with the same name with multiple slashes in them on local and remote.

I want to write a bash script calling git commands to delete the local branch and local tag, and then the remote branch and the remote tag.

For this example, assume the branch/tag name is:   `production/2020/12/10`

That branch/tag name is a hypothetical to find a solution that work for a better named branch/tag.

Any help would be so appreciated.

Comment: Type the names enclosing them in 
quotes? `"`

Answer (score 6):

Use full [refname](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrefnamegtemegemmasterememheadsmasterememrefsheadsmasterem):

```
git branch -D refs/heads/production/2020/12/10
git tag -d refs/tags/production/2020/12/10

git push --delete refs/heads/production/2020/12/10 refs/tags/production/2020/12/10
```

Comment: That's a good general rule, but note that `git branch` *assumes* a branch name (inserts `refs/heads/` for you, except with `-r` where it inserts `refs/remotes/` instead) and `git tag` *assumes* a tag name. So you don't actually need to do anything special when using `git branch` and `git tag` to delete them.

Comment: By contrast, when using `git push --delete` or equivalent, it's necessary to use the full name to make sure anything ambiguous resolves the way you want it to. :-)

Comment: Thanks, @torek, I added an example for `git push --delete`.

Comment: Is there a general guide to how Git does this sort of `refs...` resolution for you?

Comment: @matt: the gitrevisions manual page lists a six step process for resolving a refname. Unfortunately nothing seems to mention the fact that `git checkout` doesn't *use* this process, nor the items I mentioned about about `git branch` and `git tag`. Well, more precisely, `git checkout` tries the name as a `refs/heads/<branch>` name first to see if that works. If not, *then* it calls the usual resolve-ref-to-OID functions.